# Como editar um registro com campos uniques no laravel?

Tags: laravel

> Não estou conseguindo editar no laravel o registro com emails unicos,
>   sempre diz que o valor já existe quando tento salvar o registro.

URL:

```
http://dominio/dashboard/admin/franqueados/11/edit
```

REQUEST:

```
 public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->segment(4);

    $data = [
        'nome' => 'required|max:255',
        'document_number' => 'cnpj',
        'cep' => 'required',
        'logradouro' => 'required',
        'bairro' => 'required',
        'cidade' => 'required',
        'estado' => 'required',
        'numero' => 'required',
        'banco' => 'required',
        'agencia' => 'required',
        'conta' => 'required',
        'email' => "required|email|unique:users,email,{$id},id",
        'telefone' => 'required',

    ];


    return $data;
}
```

CONTROLLLER:

```
   public function update(FranquedoRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $data =  $request->all();

        $this->franqueado->findOrfail($id)->update($data);
        $request->session()->flash('message', 'Franqueado atualizado com sucesso');
        return  redirect()->back();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do seu FranqueadoRequest, você precisa dizer ao laravel para ignorar o e-mail do usuário que está sendo atualizado.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
....

public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->segment(4);

    $data = [
        'nome' => 'required|max:255',
        'document_number' => 'cnpj',
        'cep' => 'required',
        'logradouro' => 'required',
        'bairro' => 'required',
        'cidade' => 'required',
        'estado' => 'required',
        'numero' => 'required',
        'banco' => 'required',
        'agencia' => 'required',
        'conta' => 'required',
        'email' => [
             'required',
             'email',
             Rule::unique('franqueado')->ignore($id, '<campo do id caso não se chame id>')
         ],
        'telefone' => 'required',
    ];


    return $data;
}
```

Você pode verificar mais detalhes aqui:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique

Note que eu usei o 5.7 como versão da documentação e o ajuste pode variar de versão para versão.